# Paths in $\mathrm{Spec} \, \mathbb{Z}$ and Kim's proof of Siegel's theorem for $\mathbb{P}^1 \setminus \{0,1,\infty\}$

Tags: arithmetic-geometry

This is motivated by a basic number theory question I asked the previous day:
[Can there be arbitrarily many cubic fields unramified outside $\{p,\infty\}$?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/195511/can-there-be-arbitrarily-many-cubic-fields-unramified-outside-p-infty) I noted there that the answer to the corresponding question is "no" in complex function fields, i.e. for Riemann surfaces, and the reason is just that we are able to draw paths in the Riemann sphere, having as consequence that the fundamental group of $\widehat{\mathbb{C}} - S$ depends only on the number of punctures $|S|$.

The vague part of this question is this: what meaning, if any, has or can be ascribed to the idea of a path in $\mathrm{Spec} \, \mathbb{Z}$? Of course the groups $G_p := $ Galois group of the maximal unramified outside $p$ extension of $\mathbb{Q}$, are not all the same: for some $p$ there are cubic fields unramified outside $p$, for others, there aren't. But are they close to one another as abstract groups, as the idea of "connecting two primes by a path" would suggest? For instance, is it thinkable that $c_3(d) := \mathrm{dim}_{\mathbb{F}_3} \mathrm{Cl}(\sqrt{d}) \otimes \mathbb{F}_3$ might be bounded? (Recall by class field theory that $c_3(d)$ controlls the number of cubic fields with a given discriminant $d$; then a cubic field unramified outside $p$ has only a handful of possibilities $\pm p^{a}, \, a \leq 6$, for its discriminant. )

[Answer: No, this contradicts the Cohen-Lenstra heuristics, as Michael Stoll notes in the comments below. The $c_3(d)$ are bounded on average, by Davenport and Heilbronn's classic result, but it is expected following Cohen and Lenstra that for every $r$ the set of $d$ with $c_3(d) = r$ should have a certain definite density $> 0$. So the number of degree three covers of a punctured $\mathrm{Spec} \, \mathbb{Z}$ cannot be bounded by the number of punctures alone; we need also some input from the *sizes* of the punctures. On the other hand $3^{c_3(d)} \ll_{\varepsilon} d^{\varepsilon}$ is a well known hypothesis, with current record of $\varepsilon = 0.223\ldots$ due to Helfgott and Venkatesh as far as I am aware. Perhaps generalizing this conjecture there could be a sense in which $G_p$ are  "close" as abstract groups, in some quantitative sense involving an $\varepsilon$, viz. $p^{\varepsilon}$... ]

---

Anyway I had the following completely specfic question, looking to interpret the observation that various results in diophantine approximations (such as the number of solutions to $S$-unit equations, exceptions to Roth's inequality, etc.) show a dependence on $S$ only through the number of punctures $|S|$. It is  about Kim's approach to the $S$-unit equation: Does it match the diophantine results on the number of solutions? Here is what I wrote initially:

While I am not at all confident that any sense can go into the idea of paths in $\mathrm{Spec} \, \mathbb{Z}$, there is the related idea of the motivic fundamental group, which is perfectly on solid ground for a unirational variety over $\mathbb{Q}$. For $\mathbb{P}^1 - \{0,1,\infty\}$ the point of view of the motivic fundamental group has been used by Minhyong Kim to give an apparently completely new proof of the finiteness of solutions in $S$-units to the equation $x+y = 1$. All the other proofs are essentially diophantine.  If I understand correctly Kim's approach is specific to the case of $\mathbb{Q}$, but still I wondered if it could give any insight on the above kind of questions.

Hence I wanted to ask concretely the following. If none of the rest makes any sense, please take this as the real

**Question.** *Does Kim's proof of the finiteness of solutions to the $S$-unit equation produce a bound exponential in $|S|$? (Indeed, is this proof even effective?)*

I would like to study Kim's proof, but I am only beginning to do so; hence, at the moment I have no clue what the answer to this question is.
The diophantine approximations approach does produce exactly such a bound, as would be expected by the idea of paths.

Comment: Wouldn't boundedness of the 3-ranks of the class groups of quadratic fields contradict Cohen-Lenstra heuristics?

Comment: @MichaelStoll: I see... You mean property (C5) with $p = 3$ on page 56 of Cohen and Lenstra's paper, which predicts after all that for every $r$ the $3$-ranks  $= r$ for a positive density of the quadratic fields (while they are bounded on average). Thank you! (Obviously I need to get a better grasp of the heuristics... )

Comment: About clarifying the idea of paths: did you try reading this? http://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/kimm/papers/leeds.pdf

Comment: @Pasten: Not yet: thank you for bringing it to my attention!

Comment: OK, the two phrases in the title, "paths in $\mathbb{Z}$" and Kim's approach to Siegel's theorem (the idea of the motivic torsor of paths in a variety), have nothing in common and it seems indeed that the whole post was rather silly. Still I am curious whether Kim's approach gives any information of the number of solutions to the $S$-unit equation.

Comment: @Pasten: Do you know if the "$p$-adic Hodge theory" approach (Kim's proof) supplies an estimate on the number of solutions to the $S$-unit equation? (other than this being finite)

Comment: As of today, I don't think that such a bound is known to follow from Kim's proof. Nevertheless, there is some work on  computing the various objects involved in the proof, in order to get effective finiteness, see for instance 1209.0640v3

Comment: You actually want to think of a single prime $p$ as representing multiple $(\approx \log p)$ points in the geometric analogue. You can see this from the function field model, where an irreducible polynomial of large degree has many roots over an algebraically closed field.

Comment: @WillSawin: Thanks for the comment! This question of mine wasn't very good as posed. Regarding the distinction between closed and geometric points I had wondered about the following, not concerning cubic fields as such, but rather about elliptic curves: Is it conceivable that the number of elliptic curves with conductor $N$ might be bounded solely in terms of $\omega(N)$ (number of closed points), or must $\log{N}$ (number of "geometric points") must definitely be involved? Brumer and Silverman conjectured the upper bound $\ll \log{N}/\log{\log{N}}$ for the logarithm of this count...

Comment: ...which would certainly follow if the count were bounded exponentially in $\omega(N)$, like the $|S|$ in the unit equation. The standard reduction (Siegel) to the unit equation links this problem to estimating either $3$-torsion in class groups of (varying) quadratic fields or the $2$-torsion in class groups of (varying) cubic fields. Indeed, Helfgott and Venkatesh's progress about $c_3(d)$ led them to the bound $\ll N^{0.223\ldots}$ in the elliptic curves counting problem. But the latter is nonetheless different: one might wonder if $abc$ suggests, after all, an exponential bound in $|S|$?

Comment: @VesselinDimitrov I fail to see how $abc$ suggests anything along these lines, because all $abc$ bounds are in terms of the radical, not the number of prime factors.

Comment: @WillSawin: It is not at all clear that it suggests this, which is why I added the ?-mark. What I meant about abc is that it suggests that the set of minimal discriminants is bounded exponentially in $\omega(N)$. I do realize in writing this that the heuristic appeal to $abc$ here is unnecessary and irrelevant: we could work with $\Delta$ mod $6$-th powers and $S$-integral points. To get from here to $j$ we need to solve an equation $y^2 = x^3 + k$ in $S$-integers, where $k = \Delta$ itself is an $S$-integer.

Comment: (continued) As the Mordell rank of $y^2 = x^3 + k$ can be bounded exponentially in $\omega(k)$, Silverman's theorem cited 3.6 in AEC IX does indeed imply that the set of elliptic curves is bounded in terms of $|S|$ alone, i.e. by the number of closed points! (I hadn't noticed this... Sorry, this pair of questions was a mess.) Thus the answers in counting elliptic curves and cubic fields are completely different: this is the difference between cubic polynomials and cubic fields. Another question if the bound is exponential in $|S|$; this would follow if the ranks were bounded uniformly in $k$.

Comment: (..."where $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ is an $S$-unit" is what I meant to say. This is all implicit in the Brumer-Silverman paper, though they don't mention the uniformity in $\omega(N)$.)